# Putting a WP Widget in Bootstrap 3 Panel

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put each widget inside a Bootstrap 3 panel as so: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-alternatives

Here is my working code so far but the title , it is not going into the panel heading thought. How can I achieve this?

```
function create_widget( $name, $id, $description ) 
{

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __( $name ),   
        'id' => $id, 
        'description' => __( $description ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-heading"></div><div class="panel-body">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="panel-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
}
```

**Rendered Output**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Hello World</h3>      
        <div class="textwidget">
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. 
            Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris 
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. 
            Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @isherwood the <h3> title is not going into the panel heading.

Comment: Where IS it going? (See a pattern to my questions here? :) ) Please show the rendered widget HTML.

Comment: :) Apologises @isherwood - question has been updated with the rendered output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to alter the layout a bit:

```
function create_widget($name, $id, $description) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' = > __($name),
        'id' = > $id,
        'description' = > __($description),
        'before_widget' = > '<div class="panel panel-primary">',
        'after_widget' = > '</div></div>',
        'before_title' = > '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">',
        'after_title' = > '</h3></div><div class="panel-body">')
    );
}
```